# S3 and Spark: File size and File format best practices

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I need to read data (originating from a RedShift table with 5 columns, total size of the table is on the order of 500gb - 1tb) from S3 into Spark via PySpark for a daily batch job.

Are there any best practices around:

- Preferred File Formats for how I store my data in S3?  (does the format even matter?)
- Optimal file size?

Any resources/links that can point me in the right direction would also work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post has some great info on the subject:

https://mapr.com/blog/tips-and-best-practices-to-take-advantage-of-spark-2-x/

Look at the section titled: Use the Best Data Store for Your Use Case

From personal experience, I prefer using parquet in most scenarios, because I’m usually writing the data out once, and then reading it many times (for analytics).

In terms of numbers of files, I like to have between 200 and 1,000.  This allows clusters of all sizes to read and write in parallel, and allows my reading of the data to be efficient because with parquet I can zoom in on just the file I’m interested in. If you have too many files, there is a ton of overhead in spark remembering all the file names and locations, and if you have too few files, it can’t parallelize your reads and writes effectively.

File size I have found to be less important than number of files, when using parquet.

**EDIT:**

Here’s a good section from that blog post that describes why I like to use parquet:

> Apache Parquet gives the fastest read performance with Spark. Parquet arranges data in columns, putting related values in close proximity to each other to optimize query performance, minimize I/O, and facilitate compression. Parquet detects and encodes the same or similar data, using a technique that conserves resources. Parquet also stores column metadata and statistics, which can be pushed down to filter columns (discussed below). Spark 2.x has a vectorized Parquet reader that does decompression and decoding in column batches, providing ~ 10x faster read performance.